# how to remove pattern lock in a rooted android phone?

Tags: data-recovery, password

My Xperia is Running on RR-16 OS I have added 6x6 pattern unlock, it's been months I touched it so I forgot the password

is there any way to remove the pattern lock through ADB, I also have TWRP recovery installed in it so, is it possible to delete the file containing the passwords data

Thanks in advance

Comment: only if TWRP is able to decrypt without pattern it is safe to delete locksettings.db (FDE) otherwise make a backup of /data/system and try to set new pin from https://google.com/android/devicemanager

Comment: @beeshyams unfortunately i don't know how to modify locksettings.db because afaik db-wal and db-shm files will detect modifications and destroy the whole database

Comment: **outdated!** just for reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/22142940